# logback how to set destination folder for log files

Tags: logback, logback-groovy

Is there a way to set a single destination folder, such that I can specify where all log files should be created rather than having to set it on an appender by appender basis?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can define a property in the logback configuration file an use it as below

```
<configuration>

  <property name="USER_HOME" value="/home/sebastien" />

  <appender name="SPRING_LOGS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${USER_HOME}/spring.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${USER_HOME}/myApp.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Note that logback can read the variables from System properties or a separate properties file too. Follow the [manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) for more details.

Comment: You don't even have to set a property. The "user.home" system property is already there. So you could use that.

Answer (score 12):

I've wasted a lot of time configuring **Logback** to work with **Spring Boot** and I'd like to share my configuration, hoping to save other people from wasting their time.

My example is similar to Andy Dufresne's above, with one *key* difference - no `<property>` tag. This was really important in my case because if you include the `<property name="logs_dir" value="." />` you won't be able to override it using system properties, which I wanted to do like this:

```
java -jar -Dlogs_dir=~/newLogsDir yourApp.jar
```

Also note the default value is set inside the path variable - `${logs_dir:-.}`. Hope this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%-20(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight([%-5level])) %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logs_dir:-.}/system.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover monthly -->
            <fileNamePattern>system-%d{yyyy-MM}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>12</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-26(%d [%-5level]) %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a spring boot app, and I run the fat `.jar` as a systemd service.

I struggled a couple of hours on how to set the LOG_PATH relative to the user's home dir.

Here is what worked for me:

- in `application.properties` I have:

`logging.path=${HOME}/attach_logs`

- in `logback-spring.xml` I have:

`<springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_PATH" source="logging.path"/>`

`<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/console.log</file>`

References:

[Getting the user home path in application.properties in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432473/getting-the-user-home-path-in-application-properties-in-spring-boot)

[Accessing the application properties in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743386/accessing-the-application-properties-in-logback-xml)

[Spring boot logging path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268242/spring-boot-logging-path)

[logback how to set destination folder for log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764071/logback-how-to-set-destination-folder-for-log-files)