# Getting the user home path in application.properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, spring-el

This should be a quite straight forward task, but after doing quite a bit of research I'm finding it hard to find any way to do this.

I just want to create a log file in the current user's home directory. According to the [Official Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) the variables I should modify are `logging.file` and `logging.path`. But how do I get the value of the user-home into the `logging.path`?

I have tried setting it up like:

```
logging.path=#{systemProperties['user.home']}
```

but without any success.

Comment: Have you tried `${user.home}` instead...

Comment: @M.Deinum Still no. It just creates a file in the classpath.

Comment: Where are you setting those variables?

Comment: In the appication.properties file

Comment: Try as system or environment properties as setting them in the `application.properties` file might be too late.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried opening the application.properties file from the target/classes folder, the value appears correct there but I don't see the file being created.

Comment: @M.Deinum That sounds like that might just be it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78669/discussion-between-shyam-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have solved the problem. The log file in question was actually being generated in the class path only when run from the IDE (Eclipse Luna FYI). Later on when I made a jar file and ran that, the log file was being generated in the right location as specified in the `application.properties` file. I still have no clue to why it was generated in the class path when I ran it from Eclipse.

Answer (score 24):

`${user.home}` is your answer.

For example: `${user.home}/logs/app/app.log`

**Spring boot 2.2.6**

Comment: this works for me, while `${HOME}` not, i'm on win10.

Comment: @LeiYang see my comment on Chen H's answer to see why this does not work on windows.

Answer (score 18):

If you use Linux or Mac OS, you can use `logging.path=${HOME}/logs`.

`${HOME}` is substituted by the environment variable `HOME`.

Comment: Strangely enough, it works on (my) windows, but `HOME` doesn't return the windows home... I have no idea where it takes the value from. Do you know where are those environment variables coming from?

Comment: @Juh_ AFAIK $HOME is a standard linux environment variable, which does not exist on windows, hence this solution is linux specific and won't work on windows. On windows the $HOME equivalent would be the combination of  %homedrive%%homepath%. Instead of relying directly on env vars, I'd look at Adam Ostrozlik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same Issue in development environment so I tried another approach. If you have read [official document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) It also states you can give custom configurations. And logging.path will use as a default if no custom configuration provided IMO.

I want to use log4j2 so I need custom pattern and other stuff. For that I actually put the log4j2.xml configuration file into the class-path. Look at my xml conf file for more details which actually worked in both dev and production.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <properties>
        <property name="app.name">my-app</property>
        <property name="pattern">%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c - %m%n</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="my_app" append="false" fileName="${sys:user.home}\.${app.name}\logs\${app.name}.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:user.home}\.${app.name}\logs\$${date:yyyy-MM}/${app.name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/> <!-- To console -->
            <AppenderRef ref="my_app"/>
        </root>

        <AsyncLogger name="com.rameysoft.streamline.main" additivity="FALSE" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="my_app"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

`logging.path=~/logs.`

Simple solution is use `~` symbol for home directory, works well on linux/mac/windows.

**SpringBoot 2.2.6**

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Linux). I get /home/user/app/~/logs.