# Accessing the application properties in logback.xml

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to access application properties of spring boot in log back xml.

**application.properties**

```
dummy.property=hello
```

**logback.xml**

```
${dummy.property}
```

This did not work.

Does any one have idea if it will work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you name your configuration file `logback-spring.xml`, rather than `logback.xml`, you can use `<springProperty>` to access properties from Spring's environment including those configured in `application.properties`. This is [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_environment_properties):

> The  tag allows you to surface properties from the Spring Environment for use within Logback. This can be useful if you want to access values from your application.properties file in your logback configuration. The tag works in a similar way to Logback’s standard  tag, but rather than specifying a direct value you specify the source of the property (from the Environment). You can use the scope attribute if you need to store the property somewhere other than in local scope.
>
> ```
> <springProperty scope="context" name="fluentHost" source="myapp.fluentd.host"/>
> <appender name="FLUENT" class="ch.qos.logback.more.appenders.DataFluentAppender">
>     <remoteHost>${fluentHost}</remoteHost>
>     ...
> </appender>
> ```

Comment: I having issue with logback-spring.xml after renaming from logback.xml to logback-spring.xml. 

@Andy Our custom layout pattern seem override by default spring pattern layout.
Any  idea I pretend our custom layout but also can access to spring environment?

Comment: @Joey Please ask a question of your own. It’s a better way to get some help.

Comment: Shame that the springProperty tag is needed even if the variable names are identical

Answer (score 13):

According to the http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution

> Variables can be defined one at a time in the configuration file itself or loaded wholesale from an external properties file or an external resource.
>   
> ...
>   The property is not declared in the configuration file, thus logback will look for it in the System properties.

Logback can use system properties or properties defined explicitely. So you need to tell logback to use application.properties file

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

Comment: Thank you , you have no idea how relieved I am to find this solution! (for real!)

Answer (score 1):

Just add your prefix that exists in your configuration file `(properties, yaml)` like this line:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="LOGS" source="logging.path"/>
```

in:  `logback.xml`

In this case: `logging.path` is the prefix