# read value from application properties in spring-log4j2.xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

Say I have log4j2-spring.xml file with all the configuration of the appenders.
There is a way to inject to the xml value from application.properties file?

My spring-log4j2.xml look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <Syslog name="ElkLogs" host="${logstash.host}" port="5002" protocol="UDP"> 
    </Syslogs>
    <Async name="AsyncElkLogs">
    <AppenderRef ref="ElkLogs"
    </Async> 
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="AsyncElkLogs"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

my application-dev.properties file:

```
logstash.host=elk-dev-1
```

my application-prod.properties file:

```
logstash.host=elk-prod-1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the application properties in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743386/accessing-the-application-properties-in-logback-xml)

Comment: I am looking for a solution to log4j2 framework , the answer you mentioned is for logback framework

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
 <property name="locations">
<list>
  <value>file:/relase/location1env/env1.properties</value>
  <value>file:/relase/location2env/env2.properties</value>
</list>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 application.properties files , 1 for each enviroment.

Comment: Provide location with multiple values in below manner. in any env only one file will be there and that will be picked up..<list>
  <value>classpath:env1.properties</value> <value>classpath:env2.properties</value>
</list>

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to my problem that decrease the coupling between the enviroments.

I created two configuration files, one for each enviroment with the names `spring-log4j2-dev.xml` and `spring-log4j2-prod.xml`

and edit my `application.properties` files to look like that:

**application-dev.properties**:

```
logging.config=classpath:spring-log4j2-dev.xml
```

**application.properties**:

```
logging.config=classpath:spring-log4j2-prod.xml
```