# Conditional check for the value read from application.properties in logback.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am reading the ${name} which contains value as UserService from application.properties, I need to conditionally perform these below operation in logback.xml

```
 <property name="myprop"
        value="#{'${name}' == 'UserService' ? '1' : '2' }"/>
```

But when I print myProp i am getting

```
#{'UserService' == 'UserService' ? '1' : '2' }
```

But I need to print it either 1 or 2 based on condition.
**Or If My approach is wrong, how can I do the condtional checking in logback.xml**

Comment: Where do you see in logback documentation that it allows expressions in properties?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Unable to use Spring Property Placeholders in logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743386/accessing-the-application-properties-in-logback-xml),
we make use of `springProperty` tag in *logback-spring.xml* to read property value.

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="nameInLogBack" source="name"/>
    ...
```

Then we can follow [Conditional processing of configuration files](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional) to add **[janino](http://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/)** dependency to
project

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Finally add the conditional property to *logback-spring.xml*

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    ...
    <if condition='property("nameInLogBack").equals("UserService")'>
        <then>
            <property name="myprop" value="1"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="myprop" value="2"/>
        </else>
    </if>
    ...
```