# Spring boot logging path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have configured the logging path property in my spring boot application.properties.

```
logging.path=
logging.file=
```

In respective of this property in application.properties. It is taking the logging file name and creating a new log file in tomcat log file directory.I checked my system properties it has set both LOG_FILE and LOG_PATH property.
I have using 1.3.6 version of spring boot. Any known issue related to this. I have read one issue and it seems to be fixed long back.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use **one** of the two properties, either you set:

- the logging file name (`logging.file`);
- **or** the path (`logging.path`).

You can't specify both at the same time.

---

**Sources**

Spring documentation is very subtle on this:

> If you want to write log files in addition to the console output you
>   need to set a `logging.file` **OR** `logging.path` property.

[springframework.guru](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/) says this:

> There is also a logging.path property to specify a path for a logging
>   file. If you use it, Spring Boot creates a spring.log file in the
>   specified path. However, **you cannot specify both the logging.file and
>   logging.path** properties together. If done, Spring Boot will ignore
>   both.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to put the log file in a specific folder and have its own specific filename, you can simply write all of them in the `logging.file`, i.e. you want the logs stored in the file `logmyapi.log` inside the folder named `logs` placed in the current directory, you can write it to:

```
logging.file=./logs/logmyapi.log
```

P.S. This will also create folders if there's no such folder with the specified name before.